# Web setup project failed to find the binary

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I'm using visual studio to build the setup project for my web application. The build failed because it seeks binary output at the bin\Debug\ folder while the binary I generated is actually under the bin folder. What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? Are you sure you added the output from the appropriate project to the deployment project? How many projects are in your solution?

Comment: 2008 professional. And there are two projects in my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared the test project. And the problem solve.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the output to be bin\Debug in your project.

You can use the

```
Build->Configuration Manager->
```

to do this.

Comment: Yes, I can change that, But why I would like to change the setup project, but not the output of my project. Release debug binary is not a good practice.

Comment: You can always add the files in your bin folder individually. Every time you build the setup it will use the new files.